# Invalid Idm User when trying to Connect to Cosmos Gui

Tags: fiware

Since the maintenance of last Thursday I haven't been able to connect to the Cosmos-gui.

As mentionned in the differents emails, i have reset my Filab password and can now access my Filab account.  Everythings works fine , except for Cosmos-gui.I get the message : "Error: invalid IdM user" , Everytime i try to connect using the correct credentials.

It's not a big problem, because I can still connect to my Cosmos session using SSH. The problem is just located on the web page giving the ssh command.

Comment: Can you make it clearer what the question to StackOverflow readers is.

Comment: Sorry. I want to know if someone face the same issue than with the Cosmos-gui and if they managed to solve the problem on their own.  As I say Cosmos work just fine, it's just the webpage "Cosmos-gui" which doesn't seems to work (at least for me) . And again i'm sorry , i browse StackOverflow a lot but it's the first question I asked, I need to get use to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the migration to the new IdM, a message from the protocol changed a little bit. It has been fixed and it should be working now. Try it.