# FIWARE Cosmos-GUI: Invalid IdM User

Tags: fiware, filab, cosmos

I have been trying to log in Cosmos-GUI to start developing my FIWARE application, but after I log in with my FILAB user/password I get "Error:Invalid IdM User"

I saw a similar question, and they said that it was caused by a migration of the server and that now it is solved, but I still have the problem ([Invalid Idm User when trying to Connect to Cosmos Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162145/invalid-idm-user-when-trying-to-connect-to-cosmos-gui)).

Comment: Since this kind of support will require I know your personal FILAB username, please, contact me at fiware-lab-help@lists.fi-ware.org

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by private email. Nevertheless, putting here the identifed problem for future reference to other potential users: if the FIWARE LAB password contains non alphanumeric characters then the Cosmos portal fails on creating the account. Currently reasearching why.